# r markdown: go to a particular line during the knitting proccess if condition occurs

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I need to knit a document but i want that if a condition occurs ( if(is.na(sta_tions[2]) == T) knit process has to skip to Line 22 and not read the code in beetween.
is the a command for it?
I found knit_exit() I need something similar, not to exit knit process but to skip some lines

thank you very much

Luca

Answer (score 0):

You could comment out parts depending on your conditional statement.

```
`r if(MyCondition) {"\\begin{comment}"}`

This is conditional text, shown when `MyCondition == FALSE`.

`r if(MyCondition) {"\\end{comment}"}`
```